# How to update column from same column in similiar table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to copy a column from one table to a new column in another table, but I get the following error.

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

This is the statement:

```
update order set  name2 = (select name from old order);
```

Comment: You need to specify how the rows from both tables need to be matched. Do you have a key in both tables that must be the same? NB: the tag you specified is wrong. NB: I have removed the PL/SQL tag, as it is plain SQL. Instead, I specified the RDMS you are on: Oracle

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a join condition betwwen the two tables; your select return all rows from the table; for example:

```
create table zzztemp1 (ID1 INTEGER, NAME1 VARCHAR2(100));
create table zzztemp2 (ID2 INTEGER, NAME2 VARCHAR2(100));


INSERT INTO zzztemp1 VALUES(1, 'JOE');
INSERT INTO zzztemp1 VALUES(2, 'ALBERT');
INSERT INTO zzztemp1 VALUES(3, 'JACK');


INSERT INTO zzztemp2 VALUES(1, NULL);
INSERT INTO zzztemp2 VALUES(2, NULL);
INSERT INTO zzztemp2 VALUES(3, NULL);


UPDATE zzztemp2 SET NAME2=(SELECT NAME1 FROM zzztemp1 WHERE
 zzztemp2.id2=zzztemp1.id1);

SELECT *
FROM zzztemp2;

rollback;


DROP TABLE zzztemp1;
DROP TABLE zzztemp2;
```